# How to track where web page visitors are coming from?

Tags: statistics, analytics

My main web page is `nmjava.com/index.html`, I have posted "nmjava.com" in different places on the web, when visitors click on the link how do I know where they are from ?

I've come up with the following method, but I wonder if there are any other ways to do it ?

```
<1> Create a few pages : Page_1.html , Page_2.html , ... Page_N.html
<2> Use 301 redirect to point them all to index.html
<3> Post the link to Page_1.html on site_1, post Page_2.html on site_2 ...
<4> When visitors on site_1 click on the link to Page_1.html, my web page access log
    will record nmjava.com/Page_1.html is clicked, and by that I can tell the
    visitor is from site_1, and if I see a log of nmjava.com/Page_N.html is clicked,
    I'll know that visitor is brought by site_N.
```

Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is one way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to analyse the HTTP referrer. [Piwik](http://www.piwik.org) is one tool that can do this.